# Swift 'error: cyclic dependency declaration found' referencing across projects

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

ApprovalTests.Swift tests another project ApprovalTests.StarterProject.MacOS on a `cron` timer. To do this, we

- check out the starter project
- run the build & test script

When we do, we get the following error:

```
error: cyclic dependency declaration found: ApprovalTests.Swift.StarterProject.MacOS -> ApprovalTests.Swift.StarterProject.MacOS
```

This error does *not* show up if we build it directly from the starter project.

Answer (score 4):

The circular dependency was coming from the name of the parent folder.

Solution:

- Check out to a subdirectory `ApprovalTests.Swift.StarterProject.MacOS`
- `cd` into the subdirectory and run the tests

To be clear:

- `ApprovalTests.Swift/run_tests.sh` would **fail** with a circular dependency problem
- `ApprovalTests.Swift.StarterProject.MacOS/run_tests.sh` would **succeed**, even though the contents of these folders were identical